# Posting youtube video on facebook wall with facebook SDK in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-youtube-api

Can we upload you tube videos to a Facebook account wall via the Facebook SDK using android?

Please give me some example?

Answer (score 0):

```
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(),
                    FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
                String link = "<-GET YOUR YOUTUBE LINK HERE";
                // Publish the post using the Share Dialog
                FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(
                        this)
                        .setName(Id) 
                        .setLink(link)
                        .build();
                uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

            }

                public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data,
                new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall,
                            Exception error, Bundle data) {
                        Log.e("Activity",
                                String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(
                            FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
                        Log.i("Activity", "Success!");
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: I placed this code in a method postVideo() and called the method when a button is clicked. But I'm getting NullPointerException at FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog()  line..  I am not knowing why i'm getting this NullPointerException.. Could you plz tell me..  Thanks in advance..